# Symfony: Custom subform validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, constraints

I have form witch uses custom non-mapped subform.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('subtype', 'my-subtype');
    }
}
```

The subform is consisting of multiple fields and I need to perform additional check on both of them together. The Callback constraint is perfect for the job. However I can not find a way how to add this constraint on the subform as a whole.

So far I have tried to set the Callback in setDefaultOptions() or set it with setAttribute() in buildForm() but the callback is not evaluated.

Currently I am just adding the Callback to one of the fields:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('field1', 'text')
        ->add(
            'field2', 'text',
             array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new Callback(array(
                   'methods' => array(array($this, 'validateMyType'))
                ))
        )
    ));
}

public function validateMyType($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
    // Validation failed...
    $context->addViolationAt('subtype', "mySubtypeViolation");
    return;
}
```

This however prevents me to add the violation on the whole subtype. What ever I use in addViolationAt() the violation is always added to field which hosts the Callback constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I had typo in the configuration so the callback method was not triggered. Secondly the [error-bubbling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling) was automatically set so the error was added to the whole form. So only what I needed was to manually disable it.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'error_bubbling' => false, // Automatically set to true for compound forms.
        'constraints' =>
        array(
            new Callback(array(
                'methods' => array(array($this, 'validateMyType'))
                ))
    )]);
}
```

Than the violation is added like for any other callback:

```
public function validateFacrMembership($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
    $context->addViolation("invalidValueMessage");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you can't add the Callback in setDefaultOptions(), because I just tested this and this works. That's definitely how I would have done it at first.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => new Callback([$this, 'test'])
    ]);
}

public function test($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    return;
}
```

And `test` method was executed (I checked using debugger).

Comment: Ok. This is my bad. I had bad declaration of defaults ("'constraints'**,** array(..."). How ever I still need to figure out how to add violation to its fields and to subform as whole.

Comment: You need to use the Property Path of your violations. `$context->buildViolation(...)->atPath('subtype')` should do the trick.